# Ionic 2: Configuring proxy

Tags: angular, proxy, ionic2

In angular 2, I configured the following proxy which works great:

package.json

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
```

proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/socket.io/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:1337",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "ws": true
  }
}
```

While in my Ionic 2 app:

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/socket.io/",
      "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:1337"
    }  
  ]
```

Unfortunetly it doesn't work properly, not sure if I'm missing something.

Any ideas?